# Creating a global frame?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Delphi RAD Studio 2010 on Windows platform:

Please excuse my ignorance and feel free to tell me if I am barking up the wrong tree.

I just need to know whether my idea would work in principle?

I want to create Frame ‘A’ in my project. Frame ‘A’ populates a VirtualTree whenever it  is Initialized. I also have many forms that will make use of Frame ‘A’.

I want to be able to create Frame ‘A’ and initialize in memory it when the project loads.
Then when calling any form that makes use of Frame ‘A’, I want to be able to pass Frame ‘A’ to that form either via a pointer (or some other means?) and “replace” the existing Frame that is on that form with Frame ‘A’ altogether. (not woried about placement etc).

My reasoning is that Frame ‘A’ will always do the same thing when it Initialises. Since this init can take a long time, say ‘x’, each form that uses this frame will take ‘x’ times longer to load as a result.
If the frame is pre-populated so-to-speak, this will save a lot of time, especially if the frame init creates a VirtualTree that is substantial in size.

I hope I am making sense. Any input would be appreciated for someone who might have attempted something similar to this before...

Coenraad

Comment: This may not work for you. It would mean when one form changes the treeview (expands a node, scrolls, or whatever) it will change all of the other views of that tree as well. (But a VirtualTree should never take long to load; you only load the data you need at the time you need it, and it's highly unlikely you'll need 100% of the data immediately. If you're using it that way, you're doing something wrong. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar, but using a normal TTreeView instead of a virtual tree.  If your problem is the time to load the data instead of the Tree itself then just get a copy of that data.  In my case I load up a Tree View in a CachedData class that does all my initialization.  Then when a new form is created I just Assign the .Items (TTreeNodes) like this:

```
CurrentTree.Items.Assign(CachedData.TreeView.Items);
```

When using a Virtual Tree there is a clear difference between the your data and the Tree Nodes so there are many different ways to share the underlying data. Depending on the format of your data you may be able to use it directly or make a copy of it to pass into the new form.

In general the type of approach you describe is possible and useful.  You will probably get a  more specific answer if you describe what your initialization code is doing and what type of data structures you are loading (dataset, string list, arrays, custom objects, etc.).